# record.factory is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically this is the code of AppComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APICommunicationService } from './api-comm/api-communication.service';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  vara = 'eksid';
  responseData: any;

  constructor(private apiCommunicationService: APICommunicationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDataFromAPI({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.responseData = data;
        // Process the received data as needed
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        // Handle errors
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('Request completed successfully');
        // Additional actions after completion if needed
      }
    });
  }

  API_request_test(): void {
    this.vara = this.responseData;
  }

  getDataFromAPI(observer: Observer<any>): void {
    this.apiCommunicationService.getData().subscribe(observer);
  }
}
```

And this below is the API connection service code:

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule 
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [/* ... */] 
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class APICommunicationService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://localhost:7023/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/Test`); 
  }
}
```

I am not good with angular. Basically when even trying to start the app I'm getting an error like this:

```
record.factory is not a function
    at eval (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6168:43)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:867:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6167:17)
    at R3Injector.get (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6037:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:15426:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4116:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4164:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11987:19)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/src/app/app.component.ts:10:26)
    at getNodeInjectable (d:/Orch_front_ANGU/Orch_front/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4370:44
```

When I delete the standalone thing I'll get an error about it so it must stay there.
This error.

When I delete the standalone thing I'll get an error about it so it must stay there.
This error comes up when I start the app and going into link ,,http://localhost:4200/" will call this error.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't have "enableIvy" in my app

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This is a module
@NgModule({ ... })
// This is what you should have, so remove the above
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class APICommunicationService { ... }
```

Also, I don't know what you did with the standalone part of your application, but if your app component is standalone, then you need to provide your http client into your `app.config.ts` file.

Take a look at the documentation on how to do that, and remember to always use a single decorator on your classes, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: Thank you for help, however it solved one problem while another came from the back: ,,R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_APICommunicationService -> _APICommunicationService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!" 

APICommunicationService imports HttpClientModule already...

Comment: You have to import the http client module into either your app config, or your app module. It's a global module, and services never have to import anything in their decorator. Read the documentation !